# Cannot get Client Certificate to work in HTTP Action of Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to add a HTTP Action that uses Client Certificate authentication to a logic App

When I specify the PFX file that I have generated, I get an error stating

```
The provided authentication certificate is missing the private key. The private key is required to sign the request.
```

I am using the portal directly not code

I do have the private key

How do I specify this?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> The provided authentication certificate is missing the private key. The private key is required to sign the request.
> ```

You are receiving this error because it is missing a private key. You cannot use Client Certificates for authentication without a private key.

On the Client, the Client Certificates must have a Private Key. If absent, then the certificate is ignored. For more information on this, you can refer [Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/ba-p/324623)

While Client certificate [Import](https://www.vertifi.com/help_na/setup/Certs.htm#t=Certificate_Maintenance_IE/Certificate_Import_Wizard.htm)/[Export](https://www.vertifi.com/help_na/setup/Certs.htm#t=Certificate_Maintenance_IE/Certificate_Export_Wizard.htm) you need to check the box which will provide us the private key.

**Alternate:**
Sometimes .pfx gile will not work directly. Use OpenSSL to convert them to a .pem, then back to a pfx to get it to work:

openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pem -export -out certificate2.pfx

The pfx file will work within Azure logic apps when converted to a base64 string. When the pfx file is imported into the Certificates MMC try exporting again and it works.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Call service endpoints by using HTTP or HTTPS - Azure Logic Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#client-certificate-or-azure-ad-oauth-with-certificate-credential-type-authentication)
2. [Vertifi - Digital Certificates](https://www.vertifi.com/help_na/setup/Certs.htm#t=Certificate_Maintenance_IE%2FCertificate_Import_Wizard.htm)
3. [LogicApp: Certificate Authentication for HTTP GET Action not working · Issue #51400 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51400)